# Ajax requests for php queries

Tags: php, ajax, for-loop

I am using cache plugin for wordpress website,
 Well I have few questions, actually I don't want plugin to cache the following php codes (the code is for ratings, download counts and page views.

```
<?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>

<?php setPostViews($post->ID); ?>

<?php echo getDownloadCounter(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

The owner of plugin suggested to use Ajax requests.

Can anybody please how to adjust the above code in ajax? I am new to such things.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need create different urls from which the request can retrieve the partials.

Comment: Sir,

Can you please elaborate? I am very much new to such things :)

Comment: Just create a page that displays some ratings. Through ajax you can simply pull that content and display it on your page. If you're not sure how to do it you should read up on the subject first. There are plenty of resources available online.

Comment: I am still looking for a step by step guide.